# How to convert VARCHAR2 to INTERVAL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert a VARCHAR2-value like '-28:15:00' to INTERVAL.

With a literal value, this works:

```
select interval '-09:11:36' hour to second from dual;
```

However, this does not (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected):

```
select interval MY_VARCHAR hour to second from MY_TABLE;
--comparable to select interval to_char(sysdate, 'hh:mm:ss') hour to second from dual;
```

My assumption is that the literal value is implicitly cast while the explicit varchar-value from MY_VARCHAR (or char from to_char respectively) is not valid between "interval" and "hour".

CAST like this does not work (ORA-00963: unsupported interval type):

```
select cast(MY_VARCHAR as interval hour to second) from MY_TABLE;
--comparable to select cast('09:11:36' as interval hour to second) from dual;
```

What does work is concatenating '0 ' as the day-value and cast it to INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND:

```
select cast('0 ' || '09:11:36' as interval day to second) from dual;
```

However this only works for positive values, and as long as the value for hour is below 24.
Is there a better solution than dissecting the VARCHAR-value with CASE, SUBSTR and so on?

Answer (score 3):

You need the minus sign before the days to cast it to an interval:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CAST( REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '^(-)?', '\10 ') AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND )
         AS interval_value
FROM   table_name
```

or, using simple string functions, which slightly more to type but probably more efficient (as regular expressions are slow):

```sql
SELECT value,
       CAST(
         CASE
         WHEN value LIKE '-%'
         THEN '-0 ' || SUBSTR(value, 2)
         ELSE '0 ' || value
         END
         AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
       ) AS interval_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT '-09:11:36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '09:11:36' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| VALUE | INTERVAL_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| -09:11:36 | -00 09:11:36.000000 |
| 09:11:36 | +00 09:11:36.000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bK25XlSS)

Comment: Thanks, this should work for hourly values smaller than 24. This is kind of the varchar-disection approach that I mentioned in my last sentence. But I wonder if there is an approach to do this with varchar-values instead of literals, perhaps through a simple cast (to what though?):
select interval '-28:15:02' hour to second from dual;

Comment: @makrom `CAST( value AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND )` gives the exception `ORA-00963: unsupported interval type`.

Comment: @MTO yes, the CAST function does not seem to work. This is essentially the same issue that I described with the code snippets following "CAST like this does not work (ORA-00963: unsupported interval type)". But since it works with literals there must be some compatible input type.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, which would accept hour values greater than 23, is to coerce the string into ISO format and use [the `to_dsinterval()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DSINTERVAL.html):

```
select my_varchar,
  to_dsinterval(
    regexp_replace(my_varchar, '(-?)(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)', '\1PT\2H\3M\4S')
  ) as interval_value
from my_table
```

| MY_VARCHAR | INTERVAL_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| -09:11:36 | -000000000 09:11:36.000000000 |
| 09:11:36 | +000000000 09:11:36.000000000 |
| 28:15:02 | +000000001 04:15:02.000000000 |
| -28:15:02 | -000000001 04:15:02.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DDIdc0OA)

You could do reformatting of the string with string functions, which as @MTO mentioned will be faster for large amounts of data, but it would be a bit messy:

```
select my_varchar,
  to_dsinterval(
    case
      when substr(my_varchar, 1, 1) = '-'
      then '-PT' || substr(my_varchar, 2, instr(my_varchar, ':', 1, 1) - 2)
      else 'PT' || substr(my_varchar, 1, instr(my_varchar, ':', 1, 1) - 1)
    end || 'H'
    || substr(my_varchar, instr(my_varchar, ':', 1, 1) + 1,
      instr(my_varchar, ':', 1, 2) - instr(my_varchar, ':', 1, 1) - 1) || 'M'
    || substr(my_varchar, instr(my_varchar, ':', 1, 2) + 1) || 'S'
  ) as interval_value
from my_table
```

| MY_VARCHAR | INTERVAL_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| -09:11:36 | -000000000 09:11:36.000000000 |
| 09:11:36 | +000000000 09:11:36.000000000 |
| 28:15:02 | +000000001 04:15:02.000000000 |
| -28:15:02 | -000000001 04:15:02.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E_6HGJQO)

---

As shown in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-49FADC66-794D-4763-88C7-B81BB4F26D9E), interval literals (like all literals, as the name implies) require a fixed value, not an expression or column; the quotes are not optional in the railroad diagram:

[image]

... so your first query gets ORA-00923.

And [the `cast()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75__G1514003) only supports certain conversions:

> Note 1: Datetime/interval includes DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE, TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, and INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH.

so you can't `cast(... as interval hour to second)`, and that will throw ORA-00963.

Comment: I hate to admit it, but it does indeed look like the diagram shows the quiotes as non-optional. What a pity that such a simple solution seems to be so close yet is out of reach. I guess string doctoring might be the only solution after all.